# Почему выводит true?

Tags: javascript

Все никак не могу понять почему выводит `true,` а не `false`. Ведь 1 поделить на 2 = `0.5`. Т.е не `0` и не `1`.

```js
const testNum = (num) => {
    if (num % 2 === 0 || num % 2 === 1) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
};

console.log(testNum(1));
```

Comment: ну потом что `1 % 2 === 1`. И это не поделить, а взять остаток. А 1 на 2 нацело не делится, значит в остатке будет 1, значит 1 === 1

Comment: и функция у вас всегда будет true возвращать. Потому что остаток от деления на 2 либо 0, либо 1

Comment: Очень странно( я думал будет результат как на калькуляторе. Если не явный 0 и не 1 значит false. Чем больше изучаю js тем больше не понимаю его логику))

Comment: так тут не джс, в любом языке есть оператор деления и оператор остатка. Вы вместо `%` скорее всего хотели использовать `/`

Comment: @entithat кстати, проверил с / работает по другому. Я думал что оператор остатка работает как и деление, оказывается нет) Спасибо, буду разбираться)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ведь 1 поделить на 2 = 0.5

Если поделить 1 на 2 результат будет действительно 0.5

Однако в примере `num % 2 === 0 || num % 2 === 1` нет ни единого знака деления, а знак `%` - это **взятие остатка от деления**, а не само деление.

Например при делении 4 на 3, будет (по-школьному):

```
   4  | 3
-  --  ------
   3
   --
   1
```

т.е. остаток 1

---

При взятии остатка из двух чисел, где первое число меньше второго - очевидно будет возвращаться первое число (если второе не дробное, например, а первое - целое). Потому что остаток обычно остаётся при применении оператора к большему числу.

```
1%2 --> 1
1%242 --> 1
1%2234324 --> 1
1%87623487 --> 1

5%234 ---> 5
5%666 ---> 5
5%22398234 ---> 5

111%112 ---> 111
111%12342312 ---> 111
111%1986412 ---> 111

и т.д.
```